# Triangulating a non planar polygon in 3D space

Tags: c#, 3d, geometry, projection

I have an ordered list of vertices in 3D, that form a polygon.

I'm looking to project these onto a 2D plane (as a way to triangulate and then calculate the area of them).

I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this though, anyone have any suggestions?

Edit:

I've clarified the title to the real problem I had and posted the fairly specific solution that I used. It might come in helpful to someone at some point, even if it is a bit niche.

Comment: Just remove 'z' coord. from each vertice and you got ortogonal projection.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Won't that maybe run into some problems if the polygon is mainly along one axis though?

Comment: If the 3D polygon is non-planar projecting it to a plane will distort it. Do you want to minimize distortion, maximize area or do you have any other special requirements for the projection?

Comment: The only requirement I really need is that I can triangulate it (the end goal is that I get the area, which I was going to do by triangulating then projecting back into 3D).

Comment: But the area will depend on the projection if the polygon is non-planar.

Comment: When I say project it back, I just mean once it's triangulated I use the triangle mapping to decide in triangles in the original 3D polygon. Distortion is fine, as long as the triangles could be validly mapped to the original points.

Comment: Okay, so you want to project a non-planar polygon to a plane, triangulate it, project it back and then determine the area of the original non-planar polygon based on the triangulation, right? That only changes the problem slightly - depending on the triangulation used you will get different areas, so the problem is still not well defined.

Comment: Also note that you can not easily use a triangulation algorithm that adds new vertices because you can not unambiguously project them back. So you are left with algorithms that only use existing vertices and then you can just perform the triangulation in 3D as well as in 2D.

Comment: Do you have any advice for calculating the triangulation in 3D? The polygon I have is non planar and not closed.

Comment: What do you mean by not closed? You have only a line in 3D, not a loop?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, sorry. Just that it isn't a closed surface with a volume or anything (which as you point out, is already evident from what I wrote).

Comment: Okay, this won't work this way, the problem you stated is completely ill-defined. Take a circle - polygon with many vertices - in 3D - that could be made into a disc but also into a half sphere or cone if you triangulate it by adding new vertices inside of the circle but outside of the plane of the circle.). What are you *really* trying to do? Why do you want to calculate the area?

Comment: I mean I am just trying to calculate the area, it's for taking measurements. I guess what you're saying is that given my input it's not actually possible?

Comment: If you are really only interested in the area of the polygon then yes, you do not have sufficient information. The vertices of a polygon only determine the area of the polygon if the polygon is planar.

Comment: Ah, well, that's unfortunate. Thanks for taking the time to answer anyway, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I eventually went with, which is far from optimal, but it might help some people:

1. Begin by taking an axis aligned bounding box of the polygon you're working with (this is simple done by taking the maximum and minimum of each x, y and z value for the pointset you have).
2. Project the points you have onto each of the 3 axes, the planes of which you can get from your bounding box. For help with projecting I recommend this: [Projecting to a plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444968/project-a-point-in-3d-on-a-given-plane?rq=1)
3. From here, we now have 3 two dimensional polygons. Check if they are convex, which can be done by taking the dot product of every corner in the polygon, normalising it, and comparing it the others, if they're not all the same , it's not convex.
4. If any of them are convex, pick one and triangulate it (I used [Triangle.NET](https://triangle.codeplex.com/)). The indices of the points you get out of that will correspond to your original points, giving you a functional triangulation.

Notes:

This isn't ideal, it doesn't always work (although it will in a lot of cases). In particular if the polygon overlaps with itself.

A more suitable but still not ideal method would be the minimum bounding box, but that's a lot more complicated to work out.

Answer (score -1):

While this is not immediately obvious, the total surface vector is fully specified by the polygonal loop. Simply choose a point K, preferably inside the convex hull of your polygon vertices (not actually necessary! but it helps suppress roundoff errors), and generate a triangulation using K as the hub. The sum of the individual face vectors doesn't depend upon the choice of K. To project to a plane to generate an actual triangulated surface, you can use F to define that plane.